# Integration Tests for Smart Contracts

Tags: solidity, contract-development, testing, mocha, mock

So we write integration tests in order to test interactions between contracts. Could be interactions with on-chain contracts and also off-chain services.

When it comes to unit tests, I think I have a moderate level of understand on how to write them using mocha & chai. But when it comes to integration tests, I'm not really sure how to go about it.

When I looked online, almost everything was about unit tests.

1. **Can anybody please suggest some examples repositories that contain well written integration tests?**
2. **If I'm not wrong, there is no mocking involved in integration tests right? If there is, then can you give an example of when?**

Comment: you can fork the mainnet using hardhat or ganache and test your contract with other contracts that already deployed there.